# Using win32com to initialize a COM interface with a sub class

Tags: python, class, interface, vb6, win32com

I am trying to replace a short Visual Basic program with Python and win32com. I am failing to initializing  the COM objects called by the Visual Basic script correctly. Especially I dont know how to deal with the Visual Basic "NEW" statement and how it is used to implement the interface.

```
'#Reference {E383AE62-5C01-498F-B106-3C722BB5C2F6}#1.0#0#C:\4_2_20\dlls\NsiGPIBPlus.dll#NsiGPIBPlus
'#Reference {889D5BD5-49A2-4430-8369-B886C48FEBE5}#1.0#0#C:\4_2_20\dlls\INsiGpib.dll#NSIGpibInterface


Private oGpib As NSIGpibInterface.INsiGpib


Sub Main
    Set oGpib = New NsiGPIBPlus.cNSIGPIBPlus
    If oGpib.DeviceInit(0,16,0, 13, 10, 1) Then
        sID = oGpib.Query("*IDN?",100)
        If InStr(1,sID,"Agilent") Then
            MsgBox sID
              End If
       End If
End Sub
```

I have created a small python template to reproduce the VBA code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import win32com.client, pythoncom



gpib = win32com.client.Dispatch("NSIGpibInterface.INsiGpib")
gpib2 = win32com.client.DispatchEx("NsiGPIBPlus.cNSIGPIBPlus")


print_members(gpib)
gpib = gpib2 #<-What to do here?


print(str(gpib.DeviceInit(0,16,0, 13, 10, 1)))
print(gpib.Query("*IDN?",100))
```

The COM object NSIGpibInterface.INsiGpib does expose all the methodes I would expect (DeviceInit, Query, Write) but how do I tell it to use NsiGPIBPlus.cNSIGPIBPlus to implement those methods? Directly using NsiGPIBPlus.cNSIGPIBPlus does not work, since this COM object does not have any methods. I could not find any reference or example for this problem in the win32com documentation. Thanks for any help or advise.

I would expect there is some method how to initialize the interface.

Comment: Which VB language was it? VB6, VBA, or VB Script? The question mentions all 3 but they are distinct.

Comment: This version of basic is called NSI Basic. As far as I can see it is just a customization of VB6. It is definitively not VB Script since it has types. For reference everything runs on a Win2000 from around 2003. I can also successfully launch NSIGpibInterface.INsiGpib with win32com and call its methods, but calling them does not produce results. The methods return error codes.

Comment: On further research I found that NSI Basic is a rebrand of SAX Basic ( https://www.ftgsoftware.com/manuals/basic32.pdf) The Sax Basic Language provides the core language definition. It is Visual Basic for Applications(TM) compatible.